# Browser issue symbian

Tags: c++, webbrowser-control, symbian

i want to show browser control in my application for which i have written code

```
if (iBrCtlInterface == NULL)
{
    TRect rect(Position(), Size());
    iBrCtlInterface = CreateBrowserControlL( this, 
    rect, 
    TBrCtlDefs::ECapabilityDisplayScrollBar | TBrCtlDefs::ECapabilityLoadHttpFw,
    iCommandBase, 
    NULL, 
    NULL,
    NULL, 
    NULL,
    NULL);
}

_LIT(KUrl, "file://BrCtlSampleApp/sample1.htm");

iBrCtlInterface->LoadUrlL( KUrl );
```

which is working perfect on E32,E63 device but not working on N73 device

i do not understand as it is supported from 2nd fp3 which is not showing on 3rd edition N73 device

if any one have face same problem plz let me know

i have implemented this code from SDK example `BrCtlSampleApp` which is not also working on N73 device

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please describe how it fails - does it panic or what?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the URL format that is the culprit. You need an extra `/` with `file:` url scheme, and all those forward slashes need to be converted to backward slashes, as follows:

```
_LIT(KUrl,"file:///\\BrCtlSampleApp\sample1.htm");
```

That would still be a relative path, I would suggest you to specify a full URI, something like the following:

```
_LIT(KUrl, "file:///C:\\BrCtrlSampleApp\\sample1.htm");
```

To get the Drive on which your application is installed use `Application()->AppFullName()`, from the class which you have used to implement `CAknAppUi` or `(CxxxAppUi)`.

`AppFullName()` returns the full path to where your application in installed. Extracting the drive letter and creating the absolute URI should be trivial, once you've obtained the installation path.